# Using a non-primary key for an object property in GORM?

Tags: hibernate, orm, grails, grails-orm

Is it possible to have a domain object with a field that references a **non-primary** key on another object (I am working on a legacy database).

What I have is the `flea_name` not the `flea_id` (which is the primary key).  Is there a way to have GORM automatically pull the proper Flea object from the flea table based on a non-primary **unique** key (such as name, code, etc.), rather than its id?
Such as:

```
  class Flea {
       def id //This is the primary key in the table
       def name //This is a unique key
    }

    class Puppy {
        def flea //This is stored as the flea's unique, but non-primary,
                 // name in the puppy table
                 //The puppy table has a flea_name, not a flea_id, as would be expected
        static mapping = {
            flea column: 'flea_name'//This will point to the flea's name, 
                                    //but I want to hydrate it to be a Flea
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

short answer: you don't do it this way.

you let grails use the id to link the objects in the database. then if you need to access the fleas name you can override its `toString()` method to return the fleas name. or you access that property like any other in controllers/services or gsps.

Comment: ahh, so you're working off a legacy database... this i did not catch from your question. maybe a custom hibernate mapping will do the trick. but, honestly, idk and i dont want to google it... sry.

Answer (score 2):

Can you elaborate on why you'd want to do that? If the object relationship really is that a Puppy HAS A Flea, then you really want to link via the Id as normal.

However, if what you really mean is that a Puppy HAS MANY Fleas, then it would either have a collection of individual fleas, or more likely in this case, you don't really want a relationship here but rather Puppy has a numeric field identifying the number of fleas it has.

How does that sound?

Comment: Sorry, 'number' is not the number of fleas a dog has, but the flea's particular number.  I have changed it to 'name.'  Furthermore, the reason for this is because we are creating a new intermediary table, and the way it is loaded by the data team is by using codes/natural keys, rather than the id's of the objects (since these are the same across environments).

Comment: I see - http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20(GORM).html#5.5.2.4%20Custom%20Database%20Identity describes customising the ID with hibernate and hibernate has an 'assigned' generator which "lets the application assign an identifier to the object before save() is called." Maybe this would help you use the 'name' attribute as the primary key? Haven't tried it myself. Another option is to maybe define those entities using JPA and use those from grails http://blog.springsource.com/2010/08/26/reuse-your-hibernatejpa-domain-model-with-grails/

Answer (score 2):

You may want to have a look at [Custom ORM Mapping][1]

An example:

```
class Flea {
   def id
   def name
}

class Puppy {
      static hasMany = [fleas:Flea]

    static mapping = {
      table 'puppy'
      name column:'puppy_name'
  fleas column:'flea_name'
    }
}
```

P/s: sorry because of the link has some space in it, it's : http://grails.org/doc/1.0.x/guide/single.html#5.5.2 Custom ORM Mapping

[1]: http://grails.org/doc/1.0.x/guide/single.html#5.5.2 Custom ORM Mapping

Comment: @UBM: you can simply get flea by its name, like any other field, right?

Answer (score -1):

If Flea is consistently used in this way, in other words it is not a one off. Such that the Person table also has flea_name as the foreign key why not

```
static mapping = {
    id generator: 'assigned', name: 'name'
}
```

Depending on the version of Hibernate/Grails you are on, you might loose access to the actual id column.

Or if this is a one off case you could change Puppy

```
class Puppy{
    String fleaName

    static transients = ['flea']

    Flea getFlea() {
        Flea.findByName(fleaName)
    }
}
```